# Having trouble with undefined reference to error

Tags: c, blackberry-playbook, qnx, oggvorbis

I know there are a lot of posts related to this particular error but nothing seems to be helpful in ,my case, So please forgive me for that I am posting question after almost 2 days of research on google:(

I am working on a game for blackberry playbook, and for sound/audio I am using openal along with OggVorbis, I have downloaded blackberry port of OggVorbis from following source

https://github.com/blackberry/OggVorbis

but its integration with game is creating issue like it says undefined reference to ov_clear that is in vorbisfile.h and vorbisfile.c is compiled and I can see ov_clear in libvorbis.a qnx momentics IDE, and I have added libvorbis in my game but still I am getting these errors

Please help

Comment: Please edit your question to include how you link your game, including verbatim command line or parts of the makefile if any.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: I m building project using qnx momentics IDE and I just added library using IDE and I can see it in IDE with -l option

Comment: You could convert your project to a Makefile-based in Momentics IDE and then you might see more clearly what is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I did figure it out what was the problem. I am a C#.net programmer where it does not matter you are adding reference to a library project or main project, but here you can't add a reference to a static library in an other static library, that was the reason for these errors. Thats my understanding may be someone could guide me in a better detail way.

Regards
Ahsan